# How to inject a message into logcat via adb

Tags: android

Is there a way to inject a message into the logcat buffer via adb?
This could be useful if for testing and development.

(SO requires me to write more here, so I am writing more here (ignore this line)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the device-side 'log' command. Example:

```
adb shell log -t my_tag "About to send broadcast..."
```

The result in logcat will look like:

```
08-31 10:33:18.750  7081  7081 I my_tag  : About to send broadcast...
```